# Using JavaScript to Check Some Checkboxes but not Others

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a form, within it is a table with multiple checkboxes and text input boxes. The checkboxes do not have ids, only different attributes. I want to check off multiple boxes when I run the script in the console, but only ones with specific names (like A & C but not B). I cannot edit the HTML. This is what I've got so far.

ETA: I would need to be able to run it in the console to mark off boxes in an active webpage. Is that possible?

Also I apologize for anything that is missing that seems obvious, I am very very new to JavaScript.

```js
function chk () {
  document.querySelector('[name="A"]').checked = true; 
  }
```

```html
<form>
<table>
    <TR>
         <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="A">A:</TD>
         <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtA" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
    </TR>
<TR>
         <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="B">B:</TD>
         <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtA" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
    </TR>

<TR>
         <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="C">C:</TD>
         <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtA" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
    </TR>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: What if the condition when you want to check all the checkboxes?

Comment: Your code is correct you just have to call the function

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet", then run `chk()` in the console, it checks the checkbox. What's the question?

Comment: I get the idea that there are actually more checkboxes, more `<td>`s in your table; can you share a few more examples? Then when would `chk()` be run?

Comment: There are more boxes, they're just named after the letters in the alphabet; A, B, C, etc. I was just not calling the function, what a dumb mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The function `checkAllWithName(nam)` will set the checkmark for each `<input type=checkbox">` that has a `name` attribute of `nam` in it.

```js
function checkAllWithName(nam){
 document.querySelectorAll(`input[type=checkbox][name=${nam}]`)
 .forEach(cb=>cb.checked=true)
}
checkAllWithName("A");
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <TR>
      <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="A">A:</TD>
      <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtA" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
    </TR><TR>
      <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="B">B:</TD>
      <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtB" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
    </TR><TR>
      <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="C">C:</TD>
      <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtC" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
    </TR><TR>
      <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="A">A:</TD>
      <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtA" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
    </TR>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I need to only select specific ones, not all of them.

Comment: I was lead to believe by your question's title that you wanted "multiple" checkoxes to be checked. Your own script will definitely only check _a single_ checkbox. I changed my answer again. It will now check all the boxes with a name given in parameter `nam`.

Answer (score -2):

As its more easy, I would suggest using [document.getElementsByName("A")](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) but your code is correct too. But don't forget to call your function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <TR>
                 <TD align="left"><INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX NAME="A">A:</TD>
                 <TD align="right"><input type="text" name="effDateTxtA" value="" class="detailstyle"></TD>
            </TR>
         </table>
         </form>       
<script>
function chk () {
  document.getElementsByName("A")[0].checked = true;
}
  
chk()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using a function that returns a collection, then selecting an element from that collection is a waste when the OP already has code that returns a single element already.